# textboxes are empty on postback with bootstrap modal asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap modal in my asp.net page like this:

```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ModalUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRegister" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <p>

textboxes here


 <div class="popup-footer-wrapper">
                <div class="popup-footer-left">
                    <%-- <input type="submit" class="login-button" name="login-button" value="Sign Up">--%>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" CssClass="login-button" OnClick="btnRegister_Click"
                        UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="<%$ Resources: HRGELoggedOutMaster, Signup %>" />

                </div>
            </div>

        </p>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

i see that inside

```
  protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

all the texboxes show empty value. whatever user type in textbox. Please suggest how to fix it. It may be because of UseSubmitBehavior="false" but if i dont use it then control doesnt go to onclick event.

Comment: did you eventually get a solution?

Comment: Its quite a terrible problem, one would expect basic forms to work in a popup window.
But its a problem none the less

Answer (score 8):

The reason why the you are not seeing your posted values, is because your values are not being posted. The bootstrap modal manager uses the 'body' element as the root element to which it appends your modals. As a result your modals are now outside the 'form' element and the values are not being posted back to the server.

To fix this, change the default value of the 'manager' property as follows:

```
// Note the manager is passed to the root form element. 
// Otherwise, the modals are taken out of the form and 
// values not posted back to the server
$.fn.modal.defaults.manager = $.fn.modalmanager.defaults.manager = 'body form:first';
```

**EDIT: This is assuming you are using the [Bootstrap-Modal Extension](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/)**

Comment: Please is there a solution for bootstrap 3 that does not require the additional js component?

Comment: I would check the rendered output to see if the modal is within the form element first. Values not posting is likely down to the modal being outside of the form element. Anyhow, I would recommend using the bootstrap modal extension, it's a seamless addition that adds a lot more power to the existing control.

Comment: I can't believe I spent 1 day to find this answer! Thanks!

Comment: <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.fn.modal.defaults.manager = $.fn.modalmanager.defaults.manager = 'body form:first';
});
</script>

Answer (score 2):

Steven Anderson is right, values are not posted because modal inputs are outside the form.

I was able to workaround this problem using javascript to copy the value of the modal inputs to hidden asp.net controls.

I create a hidden asp.net control **outside** of the modal:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="MyHiddenControl" value="name" runat="server" />
```

The modal textbox I want to submit:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FormYourName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"/>`
```

My modal submit button looks like this;

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="Javascript:DoCustomPost();" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

My JavaScript function looks like:

```
function DoCustomPost()
{
var ModalTextBox = document.getElementById("FormAmenity");
var HiddenTextBox = document.getElementById("MyHiddenControl");
// This is the value I want to Post
MyHiddenControl.value = ModalTextBox.value
}
```

So when I click "submit" in my modal window a postback kicks, the value of the textbox is copied to the hidden control and I can read the value from the hidden control in code-behind:

```
Protected Sub BtnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click
Dim Something As String = MyHiddenControl.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had similar problem. I resolved this by moving the modal element inside the form element using jquery.

```
   function init() {
        var element = $('#myModal').detach();
        $($("form")[0]).append(element);        
    }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Comment: @Krishanthadesilva copy the code in the script tag, or if you don't have any add a script tag with that code inside at the end of the html.

Answer (score -2):

Use the dotnet text box, or add an id and a runat server tag to the input field.