# asp.net form fields return empty when in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to submit an asp.net form inside a bootstrap modal. for some reason all the fields return empty (if I try this with fields outside of the modal it works great). I have seen some posts about it but non of the solutions solved my issue.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">EDIT ADVERTISMENT</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        <form id="updateadform" method="post" action="#" class="basic-form" >
          <label for="title">Ad Name</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="modaltbadname" runat="server" placeholder="Ad Name"></asp:TextBox>
            <label for="title">Promotional Text</label>
            <asp:TextBox id="modaltbtbpromotional" TextMode="multiline"  Rows="3" runat="server" />
          <label for="description">Page</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="modalddpage" placeholder="Insert the page the ad refers to" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
          <label for="finish-date">Start Date</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="modaltbstartdate" runat="server" placeholder="20/01/2014" CssClass="datepicker" onchange="Page_ClientValidate();"></asp:TextBox>
          <label for="finish-date">End Date</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="modaltbenddate" runat="server" placeholder="20/01/2014" CssClass="datepicker" onchange="Page_ClientValidate();"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:CompareValidator id="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="modaltbstartdate" cultureinvariantvalues="true" display="Dynamic" enableclientscript="true"  ControlToValidate="modaltbenddate" ErrorMessage="Start date must be earlier than finish date" type="Date" setfocusonerror="true" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" text="Start date must be earlier than finish date"></asp:CompareValidator>

          <div class="right-side">
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <asp:Button type="button" ID="savead"   CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="savead_Click" OnClientClick="savevariables()" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void savead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string x = idtoupdate.Value; // this field is outside of the modal - returns its correct value
    string y = modaltbadname.Text; //returns ""

    DB.UpdateAd(modaltbadname.Text, modaltbtbpromotional.Text, modalddpage.SelectedValue, modaltbstartdate.Text, modaltbenddate.Text, int.Parse(idtoupdate.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modal will not affect the values sent to the server. However, you are manually specifying a `<form>` tag within your modal. I'm assuming that further above the mark-up you have posted or in your master page there is a `<form runat="server">` somewhere and what you may have done is nested a form within a form accidentally.

Remove the form tag inside the modal and the values should save correctly.

**Edit after comments:**

Ensure the closing `</form>` tag which matches initial `<form runat="server>` tag surrounds the modal after it appended.

*Other potential causes:*

Your code behind Page_Load event does not set `modaltbadname.Text` property unless it is wrapped like so:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
     modaltbadname.Text = "value";
}
```

Check that `OnClientClick="savevariables()"` function does not change the value before it is submitted to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! you are right about the <form runat="server"> that I have, but I think the issue is that the modal is being appended to the body, which means it is not in my ASP form and that's why the values are not caught. Tried dropping the form but it did not work.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried adding the isPostback but it does not get there when I debug it. also - the OnClientClick function was a test func to see if I get these variables on client side, and did not delete them. Anyway, I deleted it and it is still not working:(

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear - the IsPostBack suggestion was just to ensure you were not changing the value on page load because in the asp.net webforms page life cycle your page load event hits before your click event, so sometimes you can override values accidentally (but this doesn't seem to be the case).

I can't think of any other causes - my guess is it's still something to do with the textboxes not being nested within the form. If you use the chrome browser developer tools or fire bug you can inspect the form values which are sent to the server (press f12 and look at the network tab)

Comment: I am pretty sure you are right and this infact is the issue. The modal div is after the form and not inside it. I tried   $('#myModalForm').appendTo('#form1'); on my document.ready function but it does not seem to work. Any Idea what I am doing wrong? again - Many thanks for your help!

Comment: A fix to move modal within the form is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184002/textboxes-are-empty-on-postback-with-bootstrap-modal-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all excessive `<form class="form-horizontal">` tags to `<div class="form-horizontal">` was helped me.